# Adding a custom "new folder" to windows explorer context menu

Tags: windows, contextmenu, windows-explorer

I often use the current date and time to name new folders, and I have made a program that does this (i.e. it takes one argument and then creates a new folder based on the current date and time and the argument).

I was wondering how I can make it so that I get a "New DateTime Folder" displayed in my context menu in windows explorer (just below "New Folder") and that it automatically adds the date and time in-front and allows the user to enter the name. It's actually a lot like the standard "New Folder" except instead of the default name being "New Folder" it should be "DateTime" and the text shouldn't by default be marked.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

After playing around a bit I figured out a way to add a basic version of this just by editing the registry. It does not prompt for a name (It just uses a basic DD.MM.YYYY HH;MM;SS format) and does not enter explorer rename mode:

[image: Explorer New menu]

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.NewDirectoryBasedOnDate]
@="NewDirectoryBasedOnDate"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.NewDirectoryBasedOnDate\ShellNew]
"Command"="\"CMD\" /D /E:ON /c for /F \"tokens=1-9 delims=.,\\:/\" %%A IN (\"%%date%%.%%time%%\") DO for /F \"tokens=*\" %%a IN (\"%1\") do md \"%%~dpa\\%%A.%%B.%%C %%D;%%E;%%F\""
"nullfile"=hex:

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\NewDirectoryBasedOnDate]
"FriendlyTypeName"="Directory Based On Date"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\NewDirectoryBasedOnDate\DefaultIcon]
@="shell32.dll,3"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\NewDirectoryBasedOnDate\Shell\open]
"LegacyDisable"=hex:

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\NewDirectoryBasedOnDate\Shell\open\command]
@="."
```

I only tested this on WinXP and it is a bit of a hack (I had to add the fake `Shell\open\command` key for the new menu entry to show up)

By changing the command to `wscript.exe //nologo "C:\path\to\NewDateDir.wsf" "%1"` and saving the following code in NewDateDir.wsf you end up with this:

[image: Explorer New menu and WSH script]

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><job><script language="VBScript"><![CDATA[

if WScript.Arguments.Count < 1 then
    MsgBox("Bad parameter!")
    WScript.Quit(1)
end if

Set FSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Function StrFilter(s,ch,rep)
StrFilter=Join(Split(s,ch,-1),rep)
End Function

basedir=FSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.Arguments(0))
defname=Date&" "&Time
defname=StrFilter(defname,"/",".")
defname=StrFilter(defname,":",";")
name=InputBox("New folder in "&basedir,"New folder",defname)

if not IsEmpty(name) and Len(name) > 0 then
    FSO.CreateFolder(FSO.BuildPath(basedir,name))
end if
]]></script></job>
```

Even if you decide to write a shell extension I think activating explorers rename mode is going to be hard, especially if you want partial selection. You also have to remember that other programs might implement shell context menus so you can't use all kinds of undocumented explorer stuff.

Comment: It is a bit of a hack, but still fairly impressive.  Nice.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a shell extension, in particular a context menu.  [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguide1.aspx) is a pretty good walk-through on how to do it.  There is also some lower-level documentation on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144169.aspx) (for context menus in particular) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468984.aspx) (for shell extensions in general).  For your particular case I think you would [register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144110.aspx) you shell extension under the "Directory\Background" key.